# Database project deployment

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have database project in visual studio 2010. It has tables views stored procedures etc. I have created a full text index on view and in stored procedure I am using like this:

```
create proc myproc

as

select * from my view 
where contains(tblperson.fname,'Steve')

end
```

When I deploy, I get error that I can't use contains as view is not full text indexed. I want to know if there is a sequence in which database project is deployed ? means first stored proc is deployed or views are deployed. Can I change this sequence.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio Database projects are great! I have just migrated from Db_Deploy integrated with SVN to TFS Visual Studio Database projects. The database projects work by creating a self contained db schema file and when you use the VsDbCmd command for deployment, it will do a schema comparison between the project schema and the database schema to generate the delta script for you. The order in which the comparison takes place is Tables, Procs then Views, ...

I would suggest that you apply this script direct on to the database and then use the schema comparison from database to project to soak in the changes. This way the visual studio database project will create the script for you. Read more about the db comparison and walkthrough on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435.aspx.

PS - How are you managing deployments of your db project? I have automated the entire deployment suit, interested to know how others are doing it.

HTH.

Cheers, Tarun